# ASP Classic Database Connection

Tags: html, sql, asp-classic

I want to use classic ASP to open and close a connection to a SQL Server database and let it run a procedure from the database. It has no parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the connection details in ASP, change caps to the relevant information objDBRS(0) will be your first part of data from a select statement

```
Set objDBConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objDBConn.Open "Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=SQLSERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=DATABASENAME; User ID=Chris;Password=PASSWORD;"

Set objDBCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

objDBCommand.ActiveConnection = objDBConn
objDBCommand.CommandText = "SQLPROCEDURENAME"
objDBCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Set objDBRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

objDBRS.open objDBCommand,,adOpenForwardOnly

DO WHAT YOU WANT HERE

Set objDBCommand=nothing
objDBConn.Close
Set objDBConn=nothing
```

Comment: I upvoted this for being able to get in a time machine and go back to 1999.

Comment: @granadaCoder oh wait i can :D

Comment: @Haydn_JW There is no need to instantiate the `ADODB.Connection` separately pass the connection string to `.ActiveConnection` and it will instantiate it for you for the life of the `ADODB.Command`. Also `ADODB.Recordset` is expensive (unless you need some of the more uncommonly use features) instead use `.GetRows()` to convert your recordset into a 2-dimensional array. The other benefit of allowing `ADODB.Command` to instantiate the `ADODB.Connection` is it isn't then left open for the duration of the page processing using valuable resources.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tried and tested approach I use over and over again.

```vb
<%
Dim cmd, conn_string, rs, data, row, rows

'Connection String if using latest version of SQL use SQL Server Native Client
'for more examples see http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/
conn_string = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;"

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
With cmd
  'No need to build ADODB.Connection the command object does it for you.
  .ActiveConnection = conn_string
  .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
  .CommandText = "[schema].[procedurename]"
  Set rs = .Execute()

  'Populate Array with rs and close and release ADODB.Recordset from memory.
  If Not rs.EOF Then data = rs.GetRows()
  Call rs.Close()
  Set rs = Nothing
End With
'Release memory closes and releases ADODB.Connection as well.
Set cmd = Nothing

'Use Array to enumerate data without overhead of ADODB.Recordset.
If IsArray(data) Then
  rows = UBound(data, 2)
  For row = 0 To rows
    'Read data
    Call Response.Write("First Field: " & data(0, row))
  Next
Else
  'No records
  Call Response.Write("No records to display")
End If
%>
```